# Multimodal distribution in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I wish to distribute turtles according to Multimodal distribution(positive and negative) in netlogo. The turtles should be distributed along positive and negative but only along negative y axis. But NetLogo seems to provide no methods for doing this like random-normal or random-poission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the type of multimodal distribution you want. Multimodal just means there is more than one peak in the density curve. Just add together multiple distributions or choose between multiple distributions. The only thing you need to be careful about is that total probability remains 1. Here's one option that will give you a mode at +1 and another at -1 with equal variance around the two.

```
[ set num ifelse-value (random-float 1 < 0.5)
  [ random-normal -1 0.2 ]
  [ random-normal 1 0.2 ]
]
```